# Backbone view, routes - permalink

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a question on Backbone routes and views.
Assuming that there is a page with 3 views, View-1,2,3. Each view nested inside the other (view 3 inside view 2 which is inside view 1) and that view 3 is result of navigating from view 1 to view 2 to view 3.
For example, view-1 shows all customers, and view-2 shows the selected customer and view-3 shows active order(s) of the selected customer. 
Now, if I want to give a permalink to this entire view (which shows the active order(s) of a particular customer selected from a list of customers) to another user then how to design it.
Are there any good practices in this scenario.

Comment: How is this implemented currently?  Can you add some sample?
I'd assume the final url like `url/#customers/:customer-x/active-orders`, and set up 3 routes starting from `url/#customers/ ` which initializes respective views, with proper error handling and memory management.

Comment: Currently, we are not changing the URL. We are just handling the click and invoking next view from there.

Comment: "if I want to give a permalink to this entire view " - to implement this you should use backbone router and handle url's